# 2 ways ManyToMany relashionship working only in one side with NeoEloquent

Tags: laravel, neo4j, neoeloquent

I've 2 models `User` and `UserGroup` with `ManyToMany relashionship` as the following:

`UserGroup.php`:

```
  public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'IN');
    }
```

`User.php`

```
public function userGroup()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserGroup', 'IN');
    }
```

I've added a `user` in a `usergroup` like this:

`$u=User::find(myUserId)` to get user,and `$g=UserGroup::find(myGroupId)`

And `$g->users()->attach($u)` and it works perfectly fine,and when i do `$g->users()->get()` ,it works also.But when i do `$u->userGoup()->get()` it returns an empty `array`.So the relashionship work on one side only `usergroup->users` but not `user->usergroup`

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you need specify all parameters in  'belongsToMany' function

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'IN', '{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USERGROUP_ON_'IN'TABLE}', '{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USER_ON_'IN'TABLE}');

return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserGroup', 'IN', '{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USER_ON_'IN'TABLE}', '{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USERGROUP_ON_'IN'TABLE}');
```

Comment: It's a nosql graph based database,so the following concept :`{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USERGROUP_ON_'IN'TABLE}', '{COLUMN_NAME_ID_USER_ON_'IN'TABLE}` doen't exist

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the problem.The `problem` comes from the `neoeloquent ORM`.They wanted to build `a nosql schemaless graph based ORM` but their way of thinking is based on `sql that eloquent ORM is based on`.So i was supposed to explicity define the 2 way relashionship when adding users to group on both ways:

`$g->users()->attach($u)` and then `$u->userGroups()->attach($g)`.In `eloquent`,by defining `$g->users()->attach($u)`,i could get all users of a group and get the group of a given user.But in `neoeloquent` it not the case.But in the `neo4j dbms` everything works fine for the both way by creating a `one way`.So the problem is `neoeloquent`